# Blocking accent characters

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the proper way of filtering numeric values for a text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866444/which-is-the-proper-way-of-filtering-numeric-values-for-a-text-field)

I have a text field in which only numbers are to be allowed.
I used regex /^[0-9]/ , its blocking most of the characters.
But not option +e , option +n etc.

Using Macosx 10.7.3

Tried blocking alt key altogether on keydown & keyup of Text Field, but no luck

```
function block(evt) {
if(evt.altKey==true)
return false;
return true;
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You should look at this [Stack Overflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866444/which-is-the-proper-way-of-filtering-numeric-values-for-a-text-field).

Answer (score 0):

Try this function instead. It looks at the character codes and if it's not a number returns false. The 48 and 57 come from the [ASCII table](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/Professeurs/Alain/images/ASCII1.GIF). If you use it on the `onkeydown` event, it'll prevent pasting too.

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9GJ4E/)

Comment: Doesnt work on mac. Thanks anyway