# Prevent characters like quotation marks from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm using regex to only allow letters, numbers and dot (**.**)

```
$('input').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\b]+$/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
        return;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RobinvdA/xofjvhmg/)

However, one can still insert characters like ", é, ~e, #, $, etc. So i mean characters you type with the Shift key.

Also, typing characters using alt+1234 for example are still allowed.

Is there a way to prevent this on the keydown event of an input?

Comment: Pretty much the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/10866473/, which also faces the same problem.

Comment: @M42 I use \b to allow backspace. The regex works fine, but it still allows a lot of special characters. I think this is more of a javascript issue than a regex issue.

Comment: Use keypress instead keydown to prevent ALT+1...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers
keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, except in the
case of key repeats. If the user presses and holds a key, a keydown
event is triggered once, but separate keypress events are triggered
for each inserted character.

Therefore, to avoid SHIFT + KEY, ALT+ KEY, use `keypress` not `keydown`

```
$('input').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\b]+$/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
        return;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/xofjvhmg/16/)

Comment: It seems to work just fine, did you try refreshing your browser?

Comment: For me this works fine. Just one tiny little thing i noticed: when pressing ' and then a character (like e or something), e is not appearing in the textbox.

Comment: OK just tested again: to me it works fine in Chrome, but does not in Firefox 33.1